# convert a sql query into jpql (JPA)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have a JPA annotated model classes called LeadGeneration and Lead. I need to get a resultset from the above two classes with JPQL. I have done an SQL equivivalent of the result set I want. Please tell me how to convert this SQL to JPQL. Have to give generated_employee_id  and status as parameters.

```
SELECT *
FROM lead_generation lg, lead l
WHERE lg.lg_code = l.lead_generation AND lg.generated_employee_id = '111' AND l.status ='CONVERTED_LEAD'
AND (first_appointment_date between  DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01') AND NOW() );
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure lead_generation has collections of lead. Each object "." variable must be setter and getter of object.

```
SELECT * FROM lead_generation lg INNER_JOIN lg.leads l WHERE lg.generated_employee_id = :id AND l.status= :status AND (lead_generation.first_appointment_date BETWEEN :min ANd :max)

Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT * FROM lead_generation lg INNER_JOIN lg.leads l WHERE lg.generated_employee_id = :id AND l.status= :status AND (lead_generation.first_appointment_date BETWEEN :min ANd :max)");
query.setParameter("id", "111");
query.setParameter("status", "CONVERTED_LEAD");
query.setParameter("min", DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01'));
query.setParameter("max", NOW());
List<lead_generation> lead_generations = (List<lead_generation>) query.getResultList();
```

Answer (score 0):

in other ways,you can using `nativeQuery`,like this:

```
@Query(value="SELECT * FROM lead_generation lg, lead l  WHERE lg.lg_code = l.lead_generation AND lg.generated_employee_id = ?1 AND l.status ='CONVERTED_LEAD' AND (first_appointment_date between  DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01') AND NOW() )",nativeQuery=true)
List<User> findLeadGeneration(Integer id);
```

Comment: How to write jpa method for this query? SELECT * FROM do_not_track WHERE (user_id=7 ) AND ('2022-06-25' BETWEEN from_date AND to_date) OR ('2022-06-30' BETWEEN from_date AND to_date);